# Get Current active file full-address in intellij-idea

Tags: intellij-plugin

I want to get the file name of the currently open tab in the intellij-IDE-editor. Basically I am developing a plugin with Java and I want to extract the name of the currently open file from the intellij-IDE-editor programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to retrieve the current file from an action, you can query the DataContext:

```
public class TestAction extends AnAction {
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
        VirtualFile vfile = (VirtualFile) e.getDataContext().getData(DataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE.getName());

        if (vfile != null) {
            String fileName = vfile.getName();
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you have access to the current `Editor` and `Project`, you could use this:

```
PsiFile file = PsiUtilBase.getPsiFileInEditor(Editor, Project)
```